# Gulp - How to collect used files only and convert them as single files in `dest`

Tags: angularjs, automation, gulp

I am using the `gulp` for run my `angular` app. But I am facing a problem here.

1. all bower_components files are copied in `dest` ans `bower_components` folder
2. my `js` files ( say 2 ) I am getting 2 `js` files in `dest` folder

same things happening for `html` and `css` files too.

What i requires is :

1. `dest` file should have only one `html` and `js` and `css` all or minified with source map included.( if necessary )
2. Basically, the gulp need to collect the files, what just i have used in the `app` instead of collecting from the folder as `.js`.

How to do this?

here is my current `gulp` code :

```
// gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// plugins
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

// tasks
gulp.task('lint', function() {
  gulp.src(['./app/**/*.js', '!./app/bower_components/**'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'));
});
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    gulp.src('./dist/*')
      .pipe(clean({force: true}));
});
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  var opts = {comments:true,spare:true};
  gulp.src(['./app/**/*.css', '!./app/bower_components/**'])
    .pipe(minifyCSS(opts))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
  gulp.src(['./app/**/*.js', '!./app/bower_components/**'])
    .pipe(uglify({
      // inSourceMap:
      // outSourceMap: "app.js.map"
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
gulp.task('copy-bower-components', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/bower_components/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bower_components'));
});
gulp.task('copy-html-files', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
gulp.task('connect', function () {
  connect.server({
    root: 'app/',
    port: 8888
  });
});
gulp.task('connectDist', function () {
  connect.server({
    root: 'dist/',
    port: 9999
  });
});


// default task
gulp.task('default',
  ['lint', 'connect']
);
gulp.task('build', function() {
  runSequence(
    ['clean'],
    ['lint', 'minify-css', 'minify-js', 'copy-html-files', 'copy-bower-components', 'connectDist']
  );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make use of the [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref) module, which parses the build blocks in the HTML, replace them and pass those files through.

Here the example setup:

**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <!-- build:js app.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
    Hello world!
</body>
</html>
```

**gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var useref = require('gulp-useref');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/index.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Running the `gulp` now will result in having the two files in the dist folder:

- *index.html* - having the `build` block replaced by the only script tag, `<script src="app.js"></script>`
- *app.js* - the concatenation of the files listed in the `build` block of the original `index.html` file

The same can be done with the `css` files as well.

This way you will have no extra files in your dest folder, just what you have used in your app.

Answer (score 1):

```
var concat = require("gulp-concat");

gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
gulp.src(['./app/**/*.js', '!./app/bower_components/**'])
.pipe(uglify({
        output: {
            beautify: false
        },
        outSourceMap: true,
        properties    : true,
        mangle:false
    }))
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))       
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

this will concatenate all files in one bundle.js file.

Comment: yes, ok. but I requres the files from bower also. But in the bower i need to collect only required files.

Comment: all the files u will add in gulp.src([]) will be included in that one bundle.